# Action Script 3, character selection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-engine

I'm making a flash game for my assignment.
Now before I start, I'm not asking for code, what I am asking for is to see how I can make my coding efficient. (and at this point you can give me hints if you wish)

In my game the player can choose two characters. When the player chooses the first character a boolean becomes true and that player is able to play.

But what I hate about this is that I have to literally put double the code.

```
    private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {

        if (e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            if (playPrincess)
            {
                upKey = false;
                caroline.standStill();
            }
            else
            if (playSirTimmy)
            {
                upKey = false;
                timmy.standStill();             
            }
        }
    }
```

for example, from this code you can see that if the player is playing as timmy, then "playSirTimmy" is true, and if that is true then , i hope the code speaks for it self.

Here is another example.

```
    private function SirTimmyMovement():void 
    {
        if (playSirTimmy)
        {
            if (rightKey)
            {
                timmy.moveRight();
            }

            if (leftKey)
            {
                timmy.moveLeft();
            }       

            if (upKey)
            {
                timmy.moveUp();
            }
        }

    }
    private function playPrincessMovement():void 
    {
        if (playPrincess)
        {
            if (rightKey)
            {
                caroline.moveRight();
            }

            if (leftKey)
            {
                caroline.moveLeft();
            }       

            if (upKey)
            {
                caroline.moveUp();
            }
        }

    }
```

now I'm not complaining or moaning, I love coding and this is fun/challenging,  I just want to know if there is another way to shorten the code, and make it efficient.

Thank you for your time.

It's just that, when it comes to collision and enemies then things will become tedios and harder.

EDIT: for Martyn

```
    private var character:player;
    private var timmy:SirTimmy;
    private var caroline:princess;


    public function Main() 
    {
        //iniation players
        character = new player;
        timmy = new SirTimmy;
        caroline = new princess;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)
    }

    private function choosePrincess(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.target == princessBtn)
        {
            //playPrincess = true;
            level1Check();
            character = caroline;

        }
    }

    private function startLevel1():void 
    {
        if (easyMode)
        {
            //set variables

        }

        if (medMode)
        {
            //you askng for it
        }

        if (hardMode)
        {
            //set variables harder!
        }


        stage.addChild(character);







    }
```

Thank you, works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a boolean, have a single property which will store the character you have selected:

```
private var player:Player;
```

When you select the character, just update that property:

```
player = timmy; // or caroline
```

This way, all your code only needs to refer to that and can be far more generalized:

```
private function movement():void 
{
    if(player === null)
    {
        // Don't run this function if neither character has been selected yet.
        return;
    }

    if(rightKey) player.moveRight();
    if(leftKey) player.moveLeft();      
    if(upKey) player.moveUp();
}
```

Comment: private car character:player

Comment: I see what you mean! Thank you, I will apply this to my work. You have a great mind Marty, once again,  thank you!

Comment: Marty, one thing, the two players can't use the same class. Adobe doesn't like this >.< 
It was a nice concept, but it didn't seem to work. 
Thank you though, very much,

Comment: @Moynul Of course two players can use the same class, otherwise inheritance would be a useless concept. What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Your concept is great, I must admit. 

On Flash CC sirTimmy is a movieclip, and his class linkage is player
Caroline is a movieclip too, and her class linkage name can't be player because flash says "Please enter a unique class name that is not associated with other library symbols".

Comment: @Moynul You should set their *class linkage* to something unique i.e. classes named `Caroline` and `Tommy`, but set their **base class** to `Player`. The base class can be set underneath where you're setting the class linkage currently.

Comment: I have done this, but now my players are not dynamically being added to the stage.    stage.addChild(character);

Comment: @Moynul Make sure you use `new Caroline` etc rather than `new Player`.

Comment: private var character:player;
private var timmy:SirTimmy;
private var caroline:princess;

Comment: Thank you Marty! You have just taught me new knowledge! I owe you! Once again, thank you.

Comment: I believe this answer solves the short term goal, but doesn't provide much in the way of a what a good design handles. The user's issue is extremely common in game development, and the state design pattern handles this exact scenario. Regardless of programming proficiency, the user may/will encounter this issue again if they implement any sub states.

Comment: @BennettYeates Of course that is the case, I am very aware of correct game design patterns having developed my own game frameworks in multiple languages. I just don't see the point in trying to get a very beginner-level developer to understand high-level concepts and implementations. If someone tried to force this upon me when I started out, I would have probably given up and not be where I am now.

Comment: @Marty I am aware you are a knowledgable programmer, and your advice is completely accurate and respectable. Again this is just my opinion, but a beginner developing games should definitely absorb the information given in a state design pattern as it used very frequently to solve this exact issue. I don't believe that it is a difficult concept to grasp, and has sizable benefits.

Comment: @BennettYeates Again, I agree (actually I forgot to +1 your answer until now). I think your answer is definitely something the OP should come back to when more comfortable with the basics :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is what is known as a state machine, or state design pattern. So regardless of the character chosen, they utilize similar methods: **moveLeft()**, **moveRight()**, and **moveUp()**.

Gang of Four on the State Design Pattern:

*Allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.*

---

So a really basic idea with the code you presented, is to use the same state machine for both characters, and just manipulate the correct object from that state machine. Here's an example of how you can do this:

**Create the state machine! :**

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

class StateMachine {
    private var character:Player;
    private var state:String; //store the current state we are in, right, left, up etc

    public function StateMachine( character:Player ) {
        this.character = character; //set the character to control states on
    }

    //handle the input from the keyboard event
    public function handleInput( event:Object ):void {
        switch( event.type ) {
            case "keyDown":
                if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT ) {
                    state = Keyboard.RIGHT;
                }
                if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP ) {
                    state = Keyboard.UP;
                }
                if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT ) {
                    state = Keyboard.LEFT;
                }
                if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN ) {
                    state = Keyboard.DOWN;
                }
                break;
            case "keyUp":
                if ( event.keyCode == state ) {
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //on our update, apply the right function
    public function update():void {
        if ( state == KEYBOARD.RIGHT ) {
            character.moveRight(); 
        }
        if ( state == KEYBOARD.DOWN ) {
            character.moveDown(); 
        }
        if ( state == KEYBOARD.LEFT) {
            character.moveLeft(); 
        }
        if ( state == KEYBOARD.UP ) {
            character.moveUp(); 
        }
    }
```

Now here's the best part, in your handling the character movement, instead of using all the booleans for the correct player, you can let the state machine handle it. So first when the character is selected we can create a new state machine:

```
private var stateMachine:StateMachine;

private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{

    if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        if (playPrincess)
        {
            upKey = false;
            stateMachine = new StateMachine( caroline );
            caroline.standStill();
        }
        else
        if (playSirTimmy)
        {
            upKey = false;
            stateMachine = new StateMachine( timmy ); 
            timmy.standStill();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just have a movement function that handles your keyboard input, you can set your `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP` events to this function and the state machine handles both:

```
private function onKeyMovement( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {
   stateMachine.handleInput( e.keyCode );
}
```

Lastly, in your update function (whether it be an event frame or something along this lines), call `stateMachine.update();`, i.e.:

```
private function myUpdateFunction( e:Event ):void {
    stateMachine.update();
}
```

That should remove all your key booleans, and let the state machine handle all your inputs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Mr Yeates, thank you for the reply. I'm just trying the first answer, although, I will try yours even if it succeeds.
Many thanks, Moynul.

Comment: Feel free to take a look, I realize you have marked a correct answer, but in terms of game development best practices and flexibility this should be the one you go with.